# How to calculate difference between two Maps in ImmutableJS?

Tags: immutable.js

I have one parent Map and want to divide it with some logic.

```
let m = Map();
let sub1 = m.filter((el) => el.isFiltered());
```

How can I get the rest of the Map? I know that I can invert condition inside filter, but I want to know if there is some method which is analogue to [_.difference in underscore](http://underscorejs.org/#difference)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [groupBy](http://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Map/groupBy) to get both subsets with one iteration round:

```
let m = Map();
let grouped = m.groupBy((el) => el.isFiltered());
let pass = grouped.get(true)
let fail = grouped.get(false)
```

Example on jsbin: http://jsbin.com/gavikufefi/edit?js,console